# How to color the cells of a table based on the frequencies of their values from the highest to the lowest?

Tags: r, colors, datatables, frequency

I have this table

```
library(carData)

View(Salaries)

table(Salaries$rank,Salaries$discipline)
```

And I want to color the cells from the highest to the lowest and then be able to export the coloured table into excel. appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What colours to apply? What are the programming problems? Have you tried with package `openxlsx`?

Comment: Green for the highest and degrading to red for the lowest - no I haven't tried the package